# Deriving UIElement - how to receive focus

Tags: wpf, focus, uielement, frameworkelement

I created a class based on `UIElement` and my intention is to render it myself overriding `OnRender`. Rendering works fine. Next I want to implement focus management and continue with other aspects of LIFE, but overriding `GotFocus` and calling Me.Focus() in it don't do a single thing. I places my control on a Window with one another control - `TextBox`, and clicking on it doesn't do a single think. Tab doesn't set focus too, and `TextBox` is `AcceptsTab` negative. I know I will have to visualize focus somehow in `OnRender` to actually tell when the control is focused or not, but first I need to allow it to receive focus and that's where I struggle. Could you please help me out?

P.S. I tagged this with `FrameworkElement` because I don't have enough reputation to create a tag `UIElement` and leaving tags empty seemed like a silly thing to do.

Comment: `I created a class based on UIElement and my intention is to render it myself overriding OnRender. ` - Are you COMPLETELY sure you need this?? what is your control like that it can't be implemented using `Templates` and `Styles`?

Comment: Oh, I am, my control will render text, but I can't even derive TextBox, because I want not only to render some parts of text differently, but also move them around, which is unsolvable using TextBox.

Comment: I think you'd probably be better off deriving from `FrameworkElement` instead.

Comment: That helped, now my control will receive focus when I call Focus() in OnGotFocus() override. Thank you! But ugly focus cues are shown, is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: See [`FocusVisualStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744790.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

I think you'd probably be better off deriving from `FrameworkElement` instead.

Comment: This is the right answer, thanks again. However, FrameworkElement doesn't provide templating capabilities, they come with Control -- with many other things like Foreground and FontSize, that I don't want my Control to inherit. So setting a FocusVisualStyle is not a way to get rid of dashed rectangle. Neither is removing the call to base class in OnRender override.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Setting null to FocusVisualStyle didn't help, but setting an empty style did. All you need to watch out for is setting style's TargetType to Control, even tho your control derives from FrameworkElement: FocusVisualStyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Style() { TargetType = typeof(Control) }));

Comment: Yep, but the `FocusVisualStyle` is referring to the `FocusVisual`, which is a `Control`, not the `FrameworkElement` itself, that's why you must `TargetType="Control"`.

Comment: Makes sense, love to learn new stuff! Thanks for helping me out.